# Listen on a network port and save data to a text file

Tags: linux, networking, listener, port

Is there some easy way in linux to listen for data on network and save them to a text file?

Thank you.

Comment: i eventually used php socket functions to listen on that port

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Netcat is your friend here.

```
nc -l localhost 10000 > log.txt
```

Netcat will listen for a connection on port 10000, redirect anything received to log.txt.

Comment: Add the -k option to have it continue listening for multiple connections instead of just one.

Comment: FWIW, I had to use `nc -l -p 10000`

Comment: @JeffMixon What version of netcat did/do you use? The version from the netcat-openbsd package states that it is an error to use -l and -p together.

Comment: @JAB Mine (macOS nc) says that in its manpage, too, but it works. :|

Answer (score 13):

Also available is TCPDump.

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -vvvvtttAXns 1500 'port 10000'
```

Comment: tpdump will monitor a specific interface. Even if you only got one interface, it will disregard internal traffic...