# Netcat - PHP - GET

Tags: php, get, netcat

my GPS sent me to a port 8081 this log:

```
$$B130,354660046834688,AAA,35,4.649100,-74.108860,120306065413
```

I need to listen with netcat and send it to PHP

example:

```
file.php?log=$$B130,354660046834688,AAA,35,4.649100,-74.108860,120306065413
```

thanks

Comment: You need to try something first and share your code. The point of this site is to help you when you're stuck, not (just) to give you snippets.

Comment: Hello, I want to do something like this ....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934697/listen-on-a-network-port-and-save-data-to-a-text-file
everything that comes for a specific job to send a php file, I'm stuck in the parameters of netcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution .... NOT with NetCat (apparently not possible), the answer is: xinetd and Php

I solved [this tutorial](http://web.ontuts.com/tutoriales/creando-servicios-de-red-tcp-con-php-y-xinetd/) is solved in 10 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the value through [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)/[`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php). This would take care of any transcoding issues from the request being sent and received.

Are you asking though, how to listen with NetCat and send the request though?

Comment: @Javier: So basically you are asking people to write the code for you? How about giving it a shot first, this is not a pro-bono freelancer site.

Comment: No, just ask as a guide:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934697/listen-on-a-network-port-and-save-data-to-a-text-file

I'm not asking for me to develop a code php or something similar.